# How does mouse input work in 3d games?

Tags: 3d, mouse

How does a game process cursor movements? 
I know it calculates offset from the middle of the screen, but how?
What constraints is that cursor having?
Is it locked to the middle of the screen/a certain area/teleported to the middle of the screen?

Those are my questions.I didn't ask this question for game development(but i didnt find a better subsection for it), as I want to emulate this 'different' mouse input (vs desktop usage) to fix the bug that many remote computer software have(if possible, not sure it is) on linux, by emulating the mouse movement restrictions in a game (agiain, not sure if it's possible).

Answer (score 1):

This is probably better suited in stack overflow (i found a few duplicates) but,
There are a few ways this is done:

- Using a system function to lock the mouse, e.g. ClipCursor on Win32 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648380(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Confining_a_Cursor
- Use the raw mouse input library to intercept the mouse events, then adjusting the mouse back to the center (and maybe capture the mouse to the screen)
- Also using a capture, wrap the mouse around the screen (if it goes off the right side, it comes back on the left) - Blender is an example of this behavior

On linux, it looks like you might get similar behavior to #1 using XGrapPointer: https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man3/XGrabPointer.3.xhtml

Comment: Feel free to link the potential duplicates you found - it can help inform decisions about whether to close the question here, and helps users stumbling onto this question find there way to other content on the topic.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36779161/trap-cursor-in-window
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/10100/trapping-mouse-inside-window-in-opengl-with-glut/
(i found a few more)